What is an example of an explicit ln-integrable random variable
I need an as nice as possible concrete example of the distribution of an almost surely positive random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[|\ln(X)|] < \infty$. In the ideal case, I want $X$ to be a continuous random variable with explicit Lebesgue density easy to obtain using the more commonly seen random variables. If it is too hard, just explicit Lebesgue desnity would suffice. I looked up the common log-distributions but they do not seem to satisfy the conditions above.

$f_X(x)=c\frac  1 {x^{2}\ln x} $for $1<x<\infty$ ($c$ chosen so that the integral of $f_X$ is $1$).

Thank you. This completely solves my problem.

@geetha290krm I think your integral may not converge - you need the lower bound to be strictly more than 1, so you may as well make it something close to $1.303088232$ so $c=1$.

@Henry Thanks, but that was a  minor error. I should have either taken $x>2$ or replaced $\ln x$ by $ln (1+x)$.

@geetha290krm Why do you need the $\ln x$ term at all?

@Henry You can drop $\ln x$ in the denominator but verification (of $E|\ln (X)| <\infty$) is simpler if you insert that factor.

@geetha290krm Maybe, though with density $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$ for $x>1$, seeing $E[X]$ is infinite and $E[|\ln(X)|]$ is finite is easy, while finding $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}=\left[\frac1x\right]_1^\infty=1$ and   $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\ln (x)}{x^2}=\left[-\frac1x-\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right]_1^\infty=1$ is not too difficult, and even easier if you spot $|\ln (X)|$ has an exponential distribution.

@Henry I have all those arguments with me but I prefer the example I gave. It is just  a question of taste and no serious issues involved here.

A simple example is to consider $Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$ with $0 \lt \lambda \le 1$

$Y$ has density $\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ for $y >0$

$Y$ has finite expectation $\frac 1\lambda$,


and then let $X=e^Y$ implying  $Y=\log(X) =|\log(X)|$

$X$ has density $\frac{1}{x^{\lambda+1}}$ for $x > 1$ (it is a Pareto distribution)

and has infinite expectation when $\lambda \le 1$.


If you want to simplify this further, let $\lambda=1$ so the density of $X$ is $\frac1{x^2}$ for $x>1$ and the density of $Y=|\log(X)|$ is $e^{-y}$ for $y>0$.
